# Thank logged in user for file upload

Tags: php, file, upload

I need the user to be thanked in uppercase for their name.

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "Thank You, {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}. The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
```

The code above works. I've tried this:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "Thank You, ucfirst({$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}). The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
```

but that just outputs it. Any help making the user's name uppercase in this format would be appreciated.

`EDIT`

After the comment from Tim I tried applying this to the rest of the possible messages but this is not working for some reason and I'm not sure why.

```
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo " Sorry ".ucfirst($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']).", the file already exists. Please try renaming or adding a version number.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo " Sorry ".ucfirst($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']).", your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "Thank You, ".ucfirst($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']).". The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo " Sorry ".ucfirst($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']).", there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

I've tried applying the same pattern but for some reason it isn't working.

Comment: `echo "Thank You, ".ucfirst($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']).". The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";`

Comment: Hero, @tim. Add it as an answer so I can accept it for you :)

Comment: @tim I've edited the question to include everywhere your answer is relevant within the code and tried to implement it. Still no luck though, unfortunately. I'd appreciate if you could take a look

Comment: in what way does it not work? are you sure `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` is the variable you want here?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it's the one I want. I've applied your code to each instance but it only capitalises the user's name with the initially posted thank you message.

Comment: ohhhhh you want the whole name in uppercase? just use `strtoupper()` instead of `ucfirst()`

Comment: Usernames just have the first name of the user. I'm just not sure why `has been uploaded` works but `the file already exists`, `your file was not uploaded` and `there was an error` all show lowercase.

Comment: Fixed it, I'd managed to make another mistake with my testing directory but it works. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also with thanks to Tim, this works for the whole code;

```
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo " Sorry ".ucfirst($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']).", the file already exists. Please try renaming or adding a version number.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo " Sorry ".ucfirst($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']).", your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "Thank You, ".ucfirst($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']).". The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo " Sorry ".ucfirst($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']).", there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

You just need to split the sections for the text and the server input for it to work.